# How to send sms using gateway?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms, sms-gateway

I am trying to build an web application using asp.net and c#.net from which I have to send sms to some mobile phones. I bought user ID and password from go-sms.com and they have provided me this:

```
   http://<url_to_be_provided>?company=<COMPANY_LOGIN>&user=<USERID>&password=<ENCODED_PASSWORD>&gateway=<GATEWAY>&mode=BUK&type=TX&hp=<MSISDN>&mesg=<MESSAGE_CONTENT>&charge=0&maskid=<MASKID>&convert=0
```

Here is my c sharp code what I have tried so far (from this website: http://forums.asp.net/t/1883175.aspx):

```
 protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://<url_to_be_provided>?company=<COMPANY_LOGIN>&user=<USERID>&password=<ENCODED_PASSWORD>&gateway=<GATEWAY>&mode=BUK&type=TX&hp=<MSISDN>&mesg=" + txtMsg.Text.ToString() +" &charge=0&maskid=<MASKID>&convert=0"); // I am so sorry, as for confidential purpose I could not provide the values for the http link, company,user id and password

        HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();

        System.IO.StreamReader respStreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream());

        string responseString = respStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

        respStreamReader.Close();

        myResp.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Response.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

but when I am pressing send button I can't get the sms. So, I would like to request the experts over here to help me on this. How I can write code to utilize this or how can I edit my current code to get the sms on the mobile phones.

Thank you.

Comment: And the error is? Are you receiving any exception? We need more details on it.

Comment: Could you also tell us what is a value of responseString variable?

Comment: @Oscar thank you so much for taking a look into my problem. No there is no error or exception. But I am not getting the sms on my phone also.

Comment: @MichałKomorowski Thank you for your answer. I have looked into the responseString variable and it is showing "E17" which is an error number as per the documentation I received from go-sms.com and the meaning of the error is: "HP list exceeds limit,
HP not supported (country or telco code error)" But I tried to write the number with +, without + and only the number. Is there any other things that I can do?

Comment: What do you use as MSISDN? Is it consistent with the format described for example on Wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSISDN)?

Comment: @MichałKomorowski thank you so much for reminding me on MSISDN. Actually when I check the document again for MSISDN format it is written that it should be something like 601020... so, no + and no zero's but starts with the country code number. I had no idea about it so I did the mistake. Thank you so much for pointing to the problem part and helping to find the solution. +1